# Remove vertices duplicates from mesh in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mesh

I need to remove duplicated vertices from a unity mesh with a complexity better than O(n^2). I tried using SortedList and Dictionary but it seems I cannot use Vector3 as index because there is a problem with the compare method:

```
    int[] triangles = srcMesh.triangles;
    int ntriangles = triangles.Length;
    Vector3[] vertices = srcMesh.vertices;
    SortedList<Vector3, int> distinctVertices = new SortedList<Vector3, int>();
    int ind = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < nvertices; i++)
    {
        if (!distinctVertices.ContainsKey(vertices[i]))
            distinctVertices.Add(vertices[i], ind++);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < ntriangles; i++)
        triangles[i] = distinctVertices[vertices[triangles[i]]];
    foreach (Vector3 distinct in distinctVertices.Keys)
        vertices[distinctVertices[distinct]] = distinct;
    nvertices = distinctVertices.Count;`


ArgumentException: does not implement right interface
System.Collections.Generic.Comparer`1+DefaultComparer[UnityEngine.Vector3].Compare (Vector3 x, Vector3 y) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections.Generic/Comparer.cs:86)
System.Collections.Generic.SortedList`2[UnityEngine.Vector3,System.Int32].Find (Vector3 key)
System.Collections.Generic.SortedList`2[UnityEngine.Vector3,System.Int32].ContainsKey (Vector3 key)
Extrusion.Start () (at Assets/Extrusion.cs:55)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own `IComparer<Vector3>`  and pass it to the `SortedList` constructor.